How to select an element using 'cy.contains'?
I have been having issues trying to select a particular locator using 'cy.contains', because there are two elements with same "cy.contains" locator, so it keeps selecting the wrong one.
Any keyword I can use to target a particular element from a list of elements.
Here is the code:
cy.contains('manda user').click()

I was expecting it to click on the "manda user" option from a list on hiring managers dropdown, but instead it clicks on "manda user" profile at the top right on same page, because apparently the user I'm logged in with is "manda user".

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

First thing to note is cy.contains() only ever selects one element, the first element on the page containing the text.
See Single Element

Only the first matched element will be returned

So you cannot use cy.contains('manda user').eq(1) to select the second on the page.
Option 1
Move the contains criteria into the selector:
cy.get('div:contains("manda user")')    // returns all elements matching
  .eq(1)                                // take the second

Option 2
If the element you want can be selected by visibility, filter on that criteria. This occurs when the page has two versions of the dropdown for mobile and desktop layouts, but only one is visible at the current viewport size.
cy.contains('div:visible', 'manda user')


Select the parent of the correct element, in this case, the "hiring managers" dropdown, and then chain the contains call onto it.
If the "hiring manager" container has the hiring-managers id, you could:
cy.get('#hiring-managers').contains('manda user').click()


cy.get(selector).contains('manda user').click();

you can also select it using data-testid (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices)
other way to do -
cy.get(selector).should('contain', 'manda user').click();

and another way to do
is using find()  which expect to accept the selector
(https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find#__docusaurus_skipToContent_fallback)
cy.get(selector).find(otherselector).click();

and in the case of siblings use .eq()
for e.g.  cy.get('tbody>tr').eq(0)
(https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq#__docusaurus_skipToContent_fallback)
